# How to find out the values from a specific column in the results of a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with the following columns: id, firstname, lastname, category.
And let's say i have data with categories like: action, comedy, drama, horror.
My query is

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE firstname LIKE '%John%'
```

The query will bring all the records that contain 'John' in firstname, and let's assume that the records have different values for categoty: action and comedy only.

How to find out the list with all the values available in category column for this specific search.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try ‘GROUPBY’ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a distinct list of categories, where firstname is like John:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM tablename WHERE firstname LIKE '%John%'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE firstname LIKE '%John%' 
and category='category_name'
```

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT category FROM tablename WHERE firstname LIKE '%John%'
```

Simple as it looks

Answer (score 0):

If you want the category list with a count on the number of occurrencies:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM tablename WHERE firstname LIKE '%John%' GROUP BY CATEGORY ORDER BY CATEGORY
```

Comment: "ORDER BY" is missing but required